# Aggregating results from SQL results

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to aggregate some results, but I am not having any luck. Here is the SQL I am using and the actual output:

SQL Statement which produced this data:

```
SELECT 
    i.inventory_item_id, 
    i.organization_id, 
    sum(primary_transaction_quantity) as on_hand_qty
FROM mtl_onhand_quantities_detail oqd, mtl_system_items_b i
WHERE oqd.inventory_item_id = i.inventory_item_id
    AND oqd.inventory_item_id = 117567 -- just used to restrict results for this example
    AND i.organization_id = :p_organization_id
    AND oqd.organization_id = i.organization_id
GROUP BY i.inventory_item_id, i.organization_id, primary_transaction_quantity


INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,ON_HAND_QTY
117567,7651,2
117567,7651,1
```

What I need returned:

```
INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,ON_HAND_QTY
117567,7651,3
```

Basically, it needs to sum the `on_hand_qty` and only return one resulting row, if the `inventory_item_id` and `organization_id` are the same. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's with :p_organization_id?

Comment: Also what DBMS are you using?

Comment: :p_organization_id is how you define a parameter in Oracle that a user can enter during report run-time. The value they enter in is replaced where :p_organization_id is in the code.

Answer (score 4):

Okay so the main problem that you have is that you included your aggregate statement in your `GROUP BY` so your query should look like this.

```
SELECT 
    i.inventory_item_id, 
    i.organization_id, 
    sum(primary_transaction_quantity) as on_hand_qty
FROM mtl_onhand_quantities_detail oqd, mtl_system_items_b i
WHERE oqd.inventory_item_id = i.inventory_item_id
    AND oqd.inventory_item_id = 117567 -- just used to restrict results for this example
    AND i.organization_id = :p_organization_id 
    AND oqd.organization_id = i.organization_id
GROUP BY i.inventory_item_id, i.organization_id
```

Not sure what DBMS you are using however if you look up group by on google you should find many explanations as to how it works.

Now lets get on to your next problem. You are using pre ansi-92 join syntax. This is [bad](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Your code should look like this.

```
SELECT 
    i.inventory_item_id, 
    i.organization_id, 
    sum(primary_transaction_quantity) as on_hand_qty
FROM mtl_onhand_quantities_detail oqd
INNER JOIN mtl_system_items_b i
    ON oqd.inventory_item_id = i.inventory_item_id
    AND oqd.organization_id = i.organization_id
    AND i.organization_id = :p_organization_id --Added back the function now that I know it isn't a typo
WHERE 
    oqd.inventory_item_id = 117567 -- just used to restrict results for this example
GROUP BY i.inventory_item_id, i.organization_id
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm using Oracle as the DBMS.

Unfortunately, this is only a very small subset of the report and it's using the older join syntax. I kept it that way in order to maintain consistency across the report. I'm not sure how to go about rewriting the rest of it to use the other way?

Comment: It may be difficult but it's the correct way to go in the long run. I would highly recommend converting the old code if you get the time. If nothing else it's good practice. :)

Answer (score 0):

remove primary_transaction_quantity from your group by clause